# IE10 css Hover not working with touch devices

Tags: html, css, menu, touch, internet-explorer-10

Hi i have a simple css hover menu on my page but it does not seem to work on IE10 when using a touch device.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Q8T/

Html:

```
<ul class="Menu">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">First</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#1" class="Active">1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#2">2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#3">3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#4">4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Second</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#5">5</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#6">6</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#7">7</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#8">8</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.Menu, .Menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
.Menu > li {
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.Menu > li:hover, .Menu > li:active {
    position: relative;
}
.Menu li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.Menu > li > a {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.Menu > li > a:hover, .Menu > li > a:active {
    border-bottom-color: #A9A9A9;
}
.Menu li > ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
    /* to ensure that we dont leave the ul and the hovering effect stops */
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888;
    padding: 0px 2px 2px 2px;
    background-color: White;
    position: absolute;
    left: -4000px;
    /* Hack to fix animation */
    min-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
.Menu li:hover > ul, .Menu li a:active + ul {
    left: -4px;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
}
.Menu li ul > li {
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-left-color: transparent;
    padding: 0 3px;
    margin: 3px 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.Menu li ul > li:hover, .Menu li ul > li:active {
    border-left-color: #A9A9A9;
}
.Menu li ul > li.Active {
    border-left-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE 10 on Win8 seems to have a solution via an aria attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"On a page element that has a hover behavior that toggles the visibility of interactive content, set the element’s aria-haspopup property to "true" "
"When an Internet Explorer 10 user on a touch-enabled device first taps the page element, the user's experience will be identical to that of a user who hovers over the element with a cursor. Until the user taps elsewhere on the page, taps the element again, or navigates to another page, the element remains in its hover state. Additionally, default actions of the onclick event (such as navigation of a link) are not performed for the first tap on the page element."

Comment: This was the best solution, all i had i had to do is add the aria-haspopup to my a tags.

Answer (score 3):

You could add `:focus` every time you use `:hover` this will make the menu work with tabs and on mobile devices to.

Hope this helped you out.

edit: note: You could better hide the menu that folds open and make it visible on hover and focus. The way it is build now hitting tab will still go through the 'invisible' links.. And, sadly, they don't drop down on focus now.

solution?: I did some effort and found a 'fix'. [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Q8T/3/) should work. But still `:focus` should be added in the other CSS rules to make the styling OK in all cases. And when a link in the 'drop-down' is in focus the menu should stay open. (But I don't think this will cause any problem on mobile.)

I just changed a little bit of CSS:

```
.Menu li a:hover + ul,
.Menu li a:focus + ul,
.Menu li a:active + ul
{
    left: -4px;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Note the '+'s.

Comment: I tried your changes but with no success http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Q8T/1/ IE10 on my WP8 still doesn't open up the sub menu

Comment: Thanks it seems to work even tho the sub menu becomes as wide as the page (but i guess that some other IE10 bug).

Comment: It did the same in FF, It is some CSS rule that does not kick in. Not sure which one though :s

Comment: Hmm the fix you applied seems to break the menu on the desktop... after adding back ".Menu li:hover > ul" it works again..

Comment: @Petoj I'll try to fix all this afternoon (for me it is afternoon, but I'm at work :p )

Comment: @Petoj I've deleted all the existing CSS and added the basics to do the same in another way. Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Q8T/5/). As you can see you'll need to apply your design again. If this ain't working in all cases you should opt for a javascript solution OR search for another CSS on google :)